# Compile c++ file using external library from linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, terminal

I have the following files:

```
ex1.cpp    ex1.h
GLee.cpp   GLee.h
```

and I want to make it use the library (openmesh library) on the following path:

> home/xyz/Downloads/OpenMesh-2.3/src/OpenMesh/

I'm trying to execute it with this:

```
g++ -Wall -o ex1 ex1.cpp GLee.cpp -L/..path../
```

but no luck, output is:

In file included from ex1.cpp:17:0:
ex1.h:28:38: fatal error: OpenMesh/Core/IO/MeshIO.hh: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: add -I/home/xyz/Downloads/OpenMesh-2.3/src/OpenMesh/ to your g++ command

Comment: You are forgetting to show g++ the path to the header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `-I path` on the command line. So from the error, it looks like you would do:

```
g++ -Wall -o ex1 ex1.cpp GLee.cpp -I /home/xyz/Downloads/OpenMesh-2.3/src
```