# Compiling with external libraries

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, linker-errors

I am having an issue with compiling one of the sample (example codes) for a C++ based jwt library from a github project: [jwt-cpp](https://github.com/pokowaka/jwt-cpp)
I cloned it and compiled it using the steps provided in the README file, which seemed successful.

After that I did a `ldconfig`.

Now, I am trying to build the example code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jwt/jwt_all.h"
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    // Setup a signer
    HS256Validator signer("secret!");

    // Create the json payload that expires 01/01/2017 @ 12:00am (UTC)
    json payload = {{"sub", "subject"}, {"exp", 1483228800}};

    // Let's encode the token to a string
    auto token = JWT::Encode(signer, payload);

    std::cout << token << std::endl;
}
```

I compile this with a command on terminal, which says:

```
g++ -std=c++11 \
 -I/usr/local/include \
 -I/usr/local/include \
 /usr/local/lib/libjwt.a \
 /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a \
 sign.cpp -o sign
```

And it results in following error:

```
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o: In function `main':
sign.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to 
JWT::Encode(MessageSigner const&, nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, 
std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, 
std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, 
nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, 
std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>)'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o: In function 
`HS256Validator::HS256Validator(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)': sign.cpp:(.text._ZN14HS256ValidatorC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN14HS256ValidatorC5ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x21): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256' sign.cpp:(.text._ZN14HS256ValidatorC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN14HS256ValidatorC5ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x5f): undefined reference to `HMACValidator::HMACValidator(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, evp_md_st 
const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o:
(.rodata._ZTV14HS256Validator[_ZTV14HS256Validator]+0x20): undefined 
reference to `HMACValidator::Verify(nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, 
std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, 
std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, unsigned char 
const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long) const'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o:
(.rodata._ZTV14HS256Validator[_ZTV14HS256Validator]+0x28): undefined 
reference to `HMACValidator::toJson[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o:
(.rodata._ZTV14HS256Validator[_ZTV14HS256Validator]+0x38): undefined 
reference to `MessageValidator::Accepts(nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, 
std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, 
std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&) const'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o:
(.rodata._ZTV14HS256Validator[_ZTV14HS256Validator]+0x40): undefined 
reference to `HMACValidator::Sign(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, 
unsigned char*, unsigned long*) const'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o: In function `HS256Validator::~HS256Validator()':
sign.cpp:
(.text._ZN14HS256ValidatorD2Ev[_ZN14HS256ValidatorD5Ev]+0x20): 
undefined reference to `HMACValidator::~HMACValidator()'
/tmp/ccX4ghoR.o:
(.rodata._ZTI14HS256Validator[_ZTI14HS256Validator]+0x10): undefined 
reference to `typeinfo for HMACValidator'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**What have I tried:**

I have read through these questions to know what I might be doing wrong:
 [How to use libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10358745/4228131) and [compile C file using external library from linux terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389842/compile-c-file-using-external-library-from-linux-terminal), Although second question is specifically for C and not C++, the problem there and the solution is applicable to C++ as well.

I have also tried variants of command line compilation such as,

```
g++ -std=c++11 \
 -I/usr/local/include \
 -I/usr/local/include \
 -L/usr/local/lib/ \
 -lcrypto -ljwt \
 sign.cpp -o sign
```

I am familiar with the fact that when I do a `-lfoo`, the linker tries to find a libfoo.a at the location provided with `-L` option.

I have confirmed that the options that are used for compilation contains what they should.
**For `-I` options:**
I can see `jwt` and `openssl` directories in `/usr/local/include`
**For `-L` options:**
I can see `libjwt.a`, `libssl.a`, `libcrypto.a`, `libssl.so`, etc at `/usr/local/lib/`

Question:
What am I doing wrong to compile this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna kick yourself when I tell you the issue.

Put the source file, `sign.cpp` **before** the library declarations in your program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib sign.cpp  -lcrypto -ljwt -o sign
```

The reason being is that the unix linker doesn't look backwards in the command line to resolve dependencies. There's a few command line switches (e.g. `--start-group` and `--end-group`) that will adjust this behavior, but the above will get you unblocked for now.  [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter/11894269).

In the above example, I took the liberty of removing the duplicated INCLUDE path arguments. You probably don't even need the `-I/usr/local/include` or `-L/usr/local/lib` part because that's typically already in the standard compiler path.