# How to run c++ project with different external libraries without IDE?[Ubuntu]

Tags: c++, ubuntu, embedded-linux

My project is about the development of a system in the field of machine vision on embedded systems. My problem is the development of the code on Ubuntu without the use of IDEs, which in the setting of the project create many files and import libraries that do not interest me. So I wanted to find a way to do everything from scratch and in a clean way to link the different libraries and test everything via command line.

Searching on the internet I found commands to execute codes with external libraries, which passes through the different libraries from the command line, like this one:

[Compiling with external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154490/compiling-with-external-libraries)

the command shown is

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib sign.cpp  -lcrypto -ljwt -o sign
```

my problem is a bit different I would like to execute the code without having to insert every path in the bash command.

My question is simple how you should develop a program that runs on embedded c++ systems so that you don't use IDE and can test it continuously without running long commands from bash.

To get the idea with python I install the packages on the board and use them normally while with c++ I know that I have to link the external libraries I use.
Tell me if I have been unclear.
thank you in advance.

Comment: look into makefiles

Comment: @NathanOliver in what sense? can you explain better

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a makefile. In this you can write your command and the paths of the external libs.
Save it and than you can start it with "make".

Comment: so should I prepare this makefile?
then do I have to write something when I launch the g++ command?